# convert multiple rows to one select field

Tags: excel

Let's assume I have these three rows which contains name and firstname.

[image: start]

My goal is to combine these rows to a single select, so i can select the row and it should be displayed at the right, depending on what i selected. E.g. something like this:

[image: end]

How is this possible?

Comment: You can use `ComboBox` in  `ActiveX Control`. Set the ColumnCount =2,`ListFillRange` and `LinkedCell`. There will be a problem though on linked cell since it will display name just like above. I guess you can use vlookup or vba to get the firstname.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to use `CONCATENATE(R1C1,R2C1,R3C1)` ?

I can't open pictures at work